# Save to session when the application starts

Tags: java, tomcat, session-variables, tomcat8

How can I save to the session a variable at the very start of the application?
The below code isn't executed when I fist run the application..

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
     session.setAttribute("flag", true); 

     //etc... 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code wont be executed at server startup, because there is no request and therefore no session at this time. This method belongs to a servlet, which is invoked once some client hits the url mapped to it.

If you need to do something at application startup use a ServletContextListener. If you have to store some variable for "global" use in your webapp use the ServletContext. If you really have to store it to the session use an HttpSessionListener.